# invalid literal for int() with base 10: with Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

My model :
 I am getting invalid literal for int() with base 10 in Django it is working in perfectly in the shell

```
class Category(models.Model):
    cat_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True ,max_length=30)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name


class Content(models.Model):
    content_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content
```

** my view **

```
def create_blog(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.POST['title']
        content = request.POST['content']
        category = request.POST['category']

        object_of_category = Category.objects.get(cat_id = (category))

        save_post = Content(category = object_of_category, content =content)

        save_post.save()
        return redirect(create_blog,{'message':'Post created Successfully!'})
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    return render(request ,'admin/create_blog.html', {'categories' : categories})
```

Comment: Can you show full exception trace log?

Comment: @Abhijeet You have created the model in a wrong way. Django automatically takes care of primary key ID's

Comment: You don't need to add cat_id, content_id fields in the model. Django do it automatically for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I read your code and I Saw this point in your code:

```
category = request.POST['category']
```

you should attention that what you have post it
it should be int type

because in your Category model:

```
cat_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
```

is integer type

i think all of your code is ok but before

```
object_of_category = Category.objects.get(cat_id = (category))
```

check type of the category by:

```
type(category)
```

> My suggesstion is that use django.form for preventing these
>   complexities.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add models.AutoField() yourself, it is added by Django automatically, see here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields

you have to remove your custom ID's in both of the tables and change your get query

### from

```
object_of_category = Category.objects.get(cat_id = (category))
```

### to

```
object_of_category = Category.objects.get(id=category)
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you are attempting to get an id(type Integer) of value category(type String) in the following snippet:
`object_of_category = Category.objects.get(cat_id = (category))`

Also, avoid creating primary key fields unless absolutely necessary as Django does that for you automatically.

Furthermore, `Try.. Except` blocks are extremely helpful in such situations as they generate  StackTraces that show where your errors stem from.